# Gulp + BrowserSync, serve at path

Tags: gulp, browser-sync

I'm using Gulp and BrowserSync to serve my webapp at `localhost:9000`.
How can I serve the webapp at `localhost:9000/some/multi/level/path` instead?

Answer (score 7):

Browsersync's static server can be configured to serve pages from any arbitrary subpath. When initializing Browsersync's static server, add a route definition where the key is the url fragment to match and the value is the directory to be served (path should be relative to the current working directory).

Try something like this:

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browsersync = require('browser-sync').create();

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  browsersync.init({
    files: './*.html',
    startPath: '/some/multi/level/path',
    server: {
      baseDir: '-',
      routes: {
        '/some/multi/level/path': '.'
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Running `gulp watch` will start Browsersync and open a page with the contents of `./` displayed at the url `http://localhost:3000/some/multi/level/path`.

`baseDir` must be set to a non-empty string and doesn't need to be a valid path. Falsey values (`null`, `false` and empty strings) won't work.

The snippet above is a working gulpfile and was tested against Browsersync v2.18.5 and gulp v3.9.1. Here's the [complete gist](https://gist.github.com/joemaller/0254b34b88cfc6a9a665025c722891b5).

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for (the combination of `startPath`, `baseDir` and `routes` did it for me). I have a separate repo for my blog and publishing it at mainDomain.com/blog and wanted to have the url structure in dev mode correct.

Answer (score 2):

In your browsersync options pass in `startPath` to have it start on a different URL that '/'.

This doesn't change what your server is serving only the path BrowserSync will start with.

http://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/#option-startPath

Comment: Thanks, I guess it solves half the problem. The remaining half being to have BrowserSync serve the app at the same path as the startPath.

Comment: @MartinStålberg Were you ever able to solve the second half of this?

Comment: @JonHarding, unfortunately I was unable to solve it.

Comment: For a future reader. startPath as of now. seems to be ignored when using proxy. a workaround is to use require('opn')

Answer (score 1):

+1 on this.

For my test server I am using gulp-webserver:

```
 gulp.src('./public')
    .pipe(webserver({
      host: 'localhost',
      port: '8000',
      path: '/myapp', 
      fallback: 'index.html'
      directoryListing: false,
      https: true
    }))
```

Then I access the app from

`https://localhost:8000/myapp/view`

but when I use Browsersync for dev mode I have to use

`https://localhost:9000/view`

It would be really nice to have it be the same, then perhaps I would stop using gulp-webserver.

Answer (score 1):

Seems the option isn't available.
`startPath` will only change which URL is opened by browsersync.

I finally came up with a simple solution :

Just create a symbolic link from `some/multi/level/path` directory to `your app files`. Then going to `localhost:9000/some/multi/level/path` will provide the same files as going to `localhost:9000`